# Is it possible to take out a word with regular expressions using the filter method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, filter

My problem is that I can not use a loop for this problem. I'm trying to discard all words that have "q". I can only use filter, map or reduce for this problem. If I put quit in the filter, it does what I want it to do but I have to have it work for all words containing q.

I tried replacing quit with a regex.I even tried the exact word quit in the regular expression.

```
test1 = ["stop", "quit", "exit"];
function lengthOfNonQWords (test1) {
    test = test1.filter(x => x != "quit");
    str = test.toString();
    strNoSpace = str.replace(/,/g, "");
    console.log(strNoSpace.length);
}
```

Comment: Like this? `test1.filter(item => !/q/.test(item))`

Comment: no need for a regex, just use ```!item.includes(`q`)```

Comment: If you *really* wanted to use `regex` which isn't necessary in this case --  You could use --> `\b\w*[Qq]\w*\b` --> https://regex101.com/r/zoUVm8/1

Comment: As an aside to @GammaGames, if you want it to be case insensitive use `!/q/i.test(item)` - the `i` flag will make it so that it ignores case.

Comment: I love regex, but be very thoughtful before jumping to them. As the old saying goes, *"Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems."*

Comment: Thank You.. I tried so long, and so many ways unsuccessfully..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use @GammaGames way or do this:

```
test1.filter(item => !item.includes("q"))
```